# Refresh just one dropdown value instead of the whole page CakePHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP 2.x. I would like to have the dropdown in my page refresh with the new value after the modal dialog from jquery ui got closed (after submit), not the whole page refresh. How can I achieve that?

on my ArticlesController.php

```
public function admin_add() {
    //setting active link
    $this->set('active', 'new_article');

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->request->data['Article']['posted'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $this->Article->create();

        if ($this->Article->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The article has been saved'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The article could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }

    $categories = $this->Article->Category->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('categories')); 
}
```

and on my view page (admin_add.php)

```
<div>
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Article');?>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('title');
        echo $this->Form->input('author');

            //THIS IS THE DROPDOWN PART
            echo $this->Form->input('category_id');

            //THIS IS THE PART FOR CALLING THE MODAL DIALOG TO ADD A NEW CATEGORY
            echo '<div class="addNewCategory">';
            echo 'add';
            echo '</div>';               
    ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit'));?>
</div>

<!-- Modal Dialog for Adding New Category (THIS IS HIDDEN UNTIL GET CALLED AS MODAL DIALOG)-->
<div class="dialog-form" title='Create new Category'>
    <?php echo $this->Form->create('Category');?>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('name');
        ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit'));?>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">   
        $('.dialog-form').dialog({
           autoOpen: false,
           title: 'New Category',
           modal: true,
           height: 300,
           width: 350,
           close: function() {
           }
        });

        $('.addNewCategory').click(function() {
            $('.dialog-form').dialog('open');
        });


    $('.dialog-form .submit').click(function(e) {
        var value = document.getElementById('CategoryName').value;
        var data = {'data[Category][name]':value};
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'categories', 'action' => 'addmodal', 'admin' => TRUE)); ?>",
            data: data,
            success: function() {
                $('.dialog-form').dialog('close');

                //WHAT SHOULD I DO IN HERE AFTER THE DIALOG CLOSED TO UPDATE THE DROPDOWN OR IF ITS NOT IN HERE PLEASE LET ME KNOW THE SOLUTION      
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

above is some of the code for controller and view and the script. The comment with UPPER CASE is my explanation. Thank you

Comment: Your success function should pass a `data` parameter which would contain the `select` with `options` from your `POST` URL. Set that to replace the `select` that needs to be replaced.

Comment: @Matt Could you give code example based on my code above? as I don't quite understand.

Comment: check out my answer. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. All you need is for your `success` callback to replace the `select`.

The way I tend to do this is to pass the data to my background script (as you are doing), and have that script print out the `select` and `option`s I need to replace the original `select`.

```
<?php
    // background script

    // some processing...

?>

<select name="originalSelectName" id="originalSelectId">
    <option value="0">Select an Option</option>
    <?php foreach ($options as $option): ?>

    <option value="<?= $option['val'] ?>"><?= $option['label'] ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Once this prints out, your `success` callback will be triggered and you just replace the `select`.

```
$('.dialog-form .submit').click(function(e) {
    var value = document.getElementById('CategoryName').value;
    var data = {'data[Category][name]':value};
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'categories', 'action' => 'addmodal', 'admin' => TRUE)); ?>",
        data: data,
        success: function(html) {
            $('.dialog-form').dialog('close');

            // replace the drop-down
            $("#originalSelectId").replaceWith(html);
        }
    })
});
```

Notice how I added the `html` parameter to your callback? That's where the returned HTML will go on its own.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

add some classes / an id to each of those select options so that way you can identify the individual in question.

then, get the data you need, select that element, then replace its html value.

Also note that this would be a good time to use ajax. -- i agree with Samuel.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
        $('.dialog-form').dialog({
           autoOpen: false,
           title: 'New Category',
           modal: true,
           height: 300,
           width: 350,
           close: function() {
           }
        });

        $('.addNewCategory').click(function() {
            $('.dialog-form').dialog('open');
        });


    $('.dialog-form .submit').click(function(e) {
        var value = document.getElementById('CategoryName').value;
        var data = {'data[Category][name]':value};
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'categories', 'action' => 'addmodal', 'admin' => TRUE)); ?>",
            data: data,
            success: function( echoedResponseFromPHPController ) {
                $('.dialog-form').dialog('close');
                $('#dropdown_92').html( echoedResponseFromPHPController );  
            }
        })
    });
}
</script>
```

figure out what that controller you're using as the ajax endpoint/url echos / prints what you need. if you need more than just one value, put it in a php array, and `print json_encode( $yourDataArray );` and in js you'd just be using `echoedResponseFromPHPController`

then, in your ajax success callback, you would refer to the data as echoedResponseFromPHPController.options[2] or something. it is json, so as long as you understand json, you can figure out how to refer to the data.

please note that you can call `echoedResponseFromPHPController` whatever you want. i just wrote the long name for clarity's sake.

Comment: Could you show code solution based on my code above? As I've been trying but it does not work.